# React native NavigationDrawer navigation.toggleDrawer() doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, drawer

I have a button in header to open & close navigation drawer menu.
When I call below method from componentDidMount() it worked and opened the menu:

```
this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
```

But when I click the button it didn't work and just fade the screen!
Here is the component code :

```
export class Home extends BaseScreen {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return ({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800'
      }
      , headerRight: <UserCoins />
      , headerLeft: <Button onPress={params.handlePress} title='Menu' />
      , title: 'title'
    })
  }

  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
  }

  state = {
    coins: 0,
  }
  //

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      handlePress: this._handlePress.bind(this)
    });
    //here working
    this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
  }

  render() {
    return (<Text />);
  }

}

export default Home
```

My navigator structure is :

1.SwitchNavigator

2.BottomTabNavigator

3.DrawerNavigator

4.StackNavigator (Home component inside it)

Comment: I've got this exact same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can call 'navigation' that you are passing into your static NavigationOptions rather than trying to bind it in the params for navigation.

Try this  on your onPress Event for your button

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}
```